# why Redirect in not working in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having trouble with the Redirect component, I am using it in routes to redirect from '/' to '/posts' but it is throwing an error, saying possible exports are redirect with lowercase 'r' and as you know components always start with uppercase, so redirect is calling now as a function instead of component, did they change the syntax or what? I also made a separate React component as Redirect and call the redirect function in it and exports it in my app.js
[image]
[image]

I searched and found some other npm packages like react-redirect and react-router-redirect , do they work?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using react router v6.

In v6, `Navigate` is added as an alternative of `Redirect`.

Try once like this:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
.
<Route path="/" element={() => <Navigate to="/posts" />} />
```